# How can I get input ng-model of the form to add some validators dynamically in code?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I use angulardart 1.1.
I have component that contains form, something like this one

```
<my_component>
   <form name='"my_form">
      <input ng-model=''>
.... 
   </form>
</my_component>
```

How can I get input ng-model of the form "my_form" to add some validators dynamically in code?

Answer (score 2):

I`ve found solution how to get form from component that contain  fields models :

```
var form = scope.context.form;
```

where `form['Email']` will be NgModel of field named Email

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the Element via the constructor and then use `querySelector` to retrieve the `<input>`.

```dart
class MyComponent implements ShadowRootAware {
  Element element;
  MyComponent(this.element);

  @override
  void onShadowRoot(_) {
    final input = element.querySelector('input');
  }
}
```

Comment: But how can I get ng-model of this input?
I have to add some validators and angular decorators to this input